# Solving the trigonometric equation $\sin(2x)\sec x + 2\cos x = 0$ for $0 \leq x < 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this trig equation for $0 \leq x < 2\pi$. I have worked it out this far, but if I divide by $4$, won't I miss some of the possible answers? Or is this how I am supposed to do it? Please include ALL steps in your answer.

$\sin2x\sec x+2\cos x=0$

$(2\sin x\cos x)(\frac{1}{\cos x})+2\cos x=0$

$\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}+2\cos x=0$

$2\sin x+2\cos x=0$

$2(\sin x+\cos x)=0$

$(2(\sin x+\cos x))^2=0$

$4(\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x)=0$

$\frac{4(\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x)}{4}=\frac{0}{4}$

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x=0$

$1+\sin2x=0$

$\sin x=\frac{-1}{2}$

Answer: $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{11\pi}{6}$

Comment: What justifies you move from $1+\sin2x=0$ to $\sin x=\frac{-1}{2}$?

Comment: You can divide by non-zero constant without risk.  You must be careful that you do not divide by 0.  But, you have done an un-orthodox bit of algebra  in your last step.

Comment: So if I were to go back to the $2(sinx+cosx)=0$, would I then divide both sides by 2, which leaves $sinx+cosx=0$, move the cosx across the equals $sinx=-cosx$, and find the values on the unit circle where $sinx=-cosx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=\sin2x\sec x+2\cos x=2(\sin x+\cos x)\implies \sin x+\cos x=0$$

and now observe that when $\;\cos x=0\;$  we do **not** get a solution as sine and cosine do not vanish on the same points, thus *for the solution(s)* of the equation we can assume $\;\cos x\neq0\;$ , and then dividing by it

$$\sin x+\cos x=0\implies \tan x+1=0\iff \tan x=-1\iff x=\frac{3\pi}4,\,\frac{7\pi}4$$